# woo-commerce API filter product by category

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using woocommece api for mobile app development. I need to filter product by category.

I used following query for filtering products

```
'products?filter[product_cat]=watches'
```

But it also return all product.

I am using woocommence Version 3.1.2 .

What is the problem of query ?
How to overcome this issue ?

Comment: i tested and `'products?filter[product_cat]=watches'` works on api v1 not v2!!  docs: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/6564

Answer (score 5):

Due to [Woocommerce REST API V3 docummentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties) you can filter products by using this parameter:

> category  - (string) -    Limit result set to products assigned a specific category ID

it should look like

```
https://<site url>/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=category_id
```

Comment: In my product filter Category filter only not working.